# DropdownList using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to make dropdowllist using JQuery (Javascript,CSS,Html)
 How can I make this kind of dropdowllist (see picture )

[image]

I have use this code for displaying this dropdownlist (Jquery ,CSS)
             Please select country

New Delhi

California

Gurgaon

North East America

North America

South Africa

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(".signupdd_dd li a").click(function () {
        $(".chosen").removeClass("chosen");
        $(this).addClass("chosen");
        alert($(this).text());
    });
    </script>
```

Now, how I can show and hide this list ???

Comment: <div class="frmcmpstn fl">
             <a class="btn fl cll" href="#">Please select country <img src="images/dd_arow_ico.png" /></a>
                  <ul class="signupdd_dd" >
                    <li><a href="#">New Delhi</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">California</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Gurgaon</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">North East America</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">North America</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">South Africa</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>

Comment: You can edit your question..see link at the bottom of your question.

Comment: It's not very clear what you **do** want, `How can I make this kind of dropdown list` and `how can I show and hide this list?`, Do you want to learn how to do dropdown lists? If so, you could check jquery chosen here: http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/.

Comment: wow ....Thanks Esteban ....I was looking this kind of code for long time thanks again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://www.webchief.co.uk/blog/simple-jquery-dropdown-menu/#

That example uses a function that is activated when a user hovers over the item. So it's a bit different but it shows good implementation of a function which works as a medium between input and showing the dropdownlist.

What you can use is jQuery's toggle statement instead of click:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/

At the bottom of that page you will find this example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<button>Toggle</button>
<p>Hello</p>
<p style="display: none">Good Bye</p>
<script>

$("button").click(function () 
 {
   $("p").toggle();
 });
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Good luck!

Comment: instead of $("button").click(function () ... 
you would then write $("button").hover(function () ...

Comment: for example: http://jsfiddle.net/xjChy/ If you now hover over the button it will toggle the paragraph. Good luck